# Limit of $\frac{\tan{(\sin{(x)}})}{\sin{(\tan{(x)}}}$ when x approaches 0

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

How would one approach finding this limit without using Taylor's series?
  $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan{(\sin{(x)}})}{\sin{(\tan{(x)}})}$$

Comment: Just using $\sin x \approx x \approx \tan x$ is enough.  That is the first term of a Taylor series for each.

Comment: @RossMillikan Without Taylor's is requested. Of course, I agree, it can be equivalently derived from the standard limit.

Comment: @gimusi:  I admitted that, but $\sin x \approx x$ is a standard limit and we don't always call that the first term of the Taylor series (though it is).

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes of course, the fact is that you were referring indeed to Taylor in your first comment. I thought you didn't see that limitation for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT**

By standard limits use that

$$\frac{\tan{(\sin{x}})}{\sin{(\tan{x}})}
=\frac{\tan{(\sin{x}})}{\sin x}
\frac{\tan x}{\sin{(\tan{x}})}
\frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{x}{\tan x}$$

Comment: Nothing more needed...+1

Comment: @DonAntonio Just [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130/505767) maybe :)

Comment: @gimusi Luckily for me, that equation has already been proved in my class and I am able to freely use it. Thanks!

Comment: @Tomasz That's nice! Well done, then you have all what you need! Bye

Comment: @Tomasz And what about $$\frac{\sin^2 (\tan x^3)}{\tan^3(\sin^2 x)}$$

Comment: @gimusi $(\frac{\sin\tan x^3}{\tan x^3}\frac{\tan x^3}{x^3}(\frac{x}{\sin  x})^3)^2(\frac{\sin^2 x}{\tan\sin^2 x})^3$

Comment: @J.G. It was for Tomasz :)

Comment: @Tomasz And what about $$\frac{\sin^3(\tan^2(\sin (\sqrt x)))}{\tan(\sin^2(\tan^{3/2} x))}$$

Comment: @J.G. $$\frac{\tan^2 (x\log^2 x)}{\log^2 x \sin (x^2\log^2x)}$$

Comment: @gimusi That one's just two fractions, but I'm in bed.

Comment: @J.G. Then let that as an exercise for Tomasz! Good night!